# how to load the pdf through programming with animation in iphone

Tags: iphone

how load a pdf into iphone and my pdf is of 200 pages then it should allow to turn the pages as we do with  while reading book manually  means  use animation to turn a page one by one ..
Thanking you ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading a large PDF and having page flipping animation isn't very simple. You can use a UIWebView like @Jim says to load the entire thing by just pointing the UIWebView's URL to the PDF but you won't get page animation. However to get full control requires that you render the PDF page by page manually to a view, and create the view's turning animation your self. Its nontrivial, and given your question you don't sound like you know enough to realistically achieve this right off.

Comment: Ya i am new to iphone devloping can u help me out can u or can u     provide me the code

Comment: Like I said you can load it in a web view but it won't have page turning animation. Your options. Split the PDF up with 1 page per file, and flip between different webviews, or create a custom view to display the PDF and flip between them. For the animating check out CoreAnimation in the dev docs.

Answer (score 0):

Use UIWebView Control to load pdf files.

Comment: but how can u be bit  expand over it